# Is there a way to make Windows-like paths accessible from Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, path, filesystems

Recently I've installed Kali Linux 2020.1b for Windows C: partition as a second OS, because as I know kali-rolling repo has **a lot** of packages, unlike Ubuntu, Debian, ... repos. Windows 10 and Kali Linux can be loaded from the Grub now, and I got a problem when I tried to open my Eclipse IDE (Eclipse Java Photon) Workspace from NTFS partition D:. I got many errors, eclipse can't find build path jars, because they are located at D:\...\spigot-1.15.2\spigot-api-....jar. I don't want to change build path every time, when I boot to another OS. How to make Windows-like paths (like C:\ProgramData\... or D:\Java\EPModule\...) accessible from Linux? I mean exactly such paths, not their alternatives like /media/(my username)/(partition id or label)/(my files here)/.

Comment: You cannot use the same workspace for that, but you can have the same projects in different workspaces.

Comment: @howlger how can I have same projects in different workspaces? by making symlink to project? or ...?

Comment: For the second workspace use _File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_ with unchecked _Copy projects into workspace_ checkbox. Or just use _File > Open Projects from File System..._

Comment: @howlger but they all imported with windows paths in build path

Comment: What do you mean by _"paths in build path"_? Could you please show your `.classpath` file?

Comment: @howlger I removed some personal info from the `.classpath`, but didn't change anything else: https://pastebin.com/L9AE3A2h

Comment: I see. Avoid absolute paths in the _Java Build Path_ by copying these JAR into an Eclipse project and add them to the _Java Build Path_ via _Add JARs..._ instead of via _Add External JARs..._.